# SQL CTE to Find Senior Managers in Hierarchy (2nd Level from the Top)

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table of `Employee IDs` with corresponding `Manager IDs`, as shown below:

**Desired Result**: Senior Manager Column., which has the roll-up manager that directly reports to John Smith (`EmpID: 1`) or Anna White (`EmpID: 2`).

Example: Tom reports to Jack who reports to Tim who reports to Anna.

Therefore, Jack Black's Senior Manager is Tim Smith, `4`.

Tom -->  Jack --> **Tim** --> Anna

[image]

I have worked on a `CTE`, but the query returns a lot of duplicated rows. Otherwise, the `CTE` outputs the correct data.

```
   WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, EmpID as SeniorManager
        FROM Employees
        WHERE ManagerID < 3 
            AND EmpActive = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT emp.EmpID, emp.FirstName, emp.LastName, c.SeniorManager 
        FROM Employees emp
        JOIN cte c ON c.EmpID = emp.ManagerID
        WHERE emp.EmpID <> emp.ManagerID
            AND emp.EmpActive = 1
        )

    SELECT * FROM cte
```

The example data is an oversimplified version of the actual data--which lives in company database. My main question: why would CTE return duplicated rows?

Here is the example data:

```
 CREATE TABLE Employees (
  EmpID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  LastName VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  ManagerID INT NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO Employees
  (EmpID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID)
 VALUES
  (1, 'John', 'Smith', 2),
  (2, 'Anna', 'White', 1),
  (3, 'Jack', 'Black', 4),
  (4, 'Tim', 'Smith', 2),
  (5, 'Jason', 'Black', 3),
  (6, 'Tom', 'Black', 3);
```

Comment: Could you provide format data instead of image? and what's your expect result?

Comment: Can you give example data and results showing this duplication you've found?  It would appear to me that the data is the culprit, not the query.

Comment: You tagged this with sql server but your sample table is not valid t-sql. AUTO_INCREMENT is mysql syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a `level` column to represent the person hierarchy.

then only have`level = 1` people.

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT EmpID,FirstName,LastName,ManagerID,1 level
    FROM Employees 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.EmpID,t2.FirstName,t2.LastName,t2.ManagerID,level+ 1
    FROM cte t1 JOIN Employees t2
    on t1.EmpId = t2.ManagerID
    WHERE t1.ManagerID <> t2.EmpId
)
SELECT EmpID,FirstName,LastName  
FROM cte t1
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from cte tt
    WHERE tt.level = 2 and t1.EmpID = tt.EmpID
) and level = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b8cece67b3506a7a8e48ce96a348da0)

**Result**

```
mpID    FirstName   LastName    
1       John        Smith       
2       Anna        White
```

Comment: The OP wants all the employees, not just level 1.  Each row should identify its root/level1 manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH recursive cte
AS (
SELECT emp.*, 0 AS LEVEL, managerid AS supervisor
FROM employees emp
WHERE empid IN (1, 2)

UNION ALL

SELECT emp.*, cte.LEVEL + 1, CASE 
        WHEN cte.LEVEL IN (0, 1)
            THEN emp.managerid
        ELSE cte.supervisor
        END
FROM employees emp, cte
WHERE cte.empid = emp.managerid
    AND emp.empid NOT IN (1, 2)
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

After lots of troubleshooting, I've figured out the solution. Hopefully this will help someone in need :)

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, EmpID as SeniorManager
    FROM Employees
    WHERE ManagerID <= 2
        AND Active = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.EmpID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, c.SeniorManager 
    FROM tblEmployee e
    JOIN cte c ON c.EmpID = e.ManagerID
    WHERE e.EmpID <> e.ManagerID
        AND e.EmpID >= 3
        AND e.Active = 1
    )

SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, MAX(SeniorManager) SeniorManager FROM cte
GROUP BY EmpID, FirstName, LastName
```

Explanation:

- Added e.EmpID > 3 to the second part of the join. The duplicated rows are due to infinite loop, because there are 2 people with each other as the manager, so I had to exclude them.
- Select the last row for each duplicated `EmpID`. For some reason, the cte had 2 records for each `EmpID`, the first record with the `top-level manager` and the second row with the `second-level manager`. Because of this, I need to select the second row.

Edit:

My OP states the code already gives me the output that I want, except that it runs into infinite loop. That was my PRIMARY QUESTION and that was resolved after excluding the first employees from the join.

I am working on corporate data which is much more complicated than the example data shown and I cannot replicate it here nor fix the data. If someone runs into similar problems, I don't know if I can provide you with the exact solution, but hopefully the code I've provided is enough to get started.

Why I answered my own question but accepted someone else's answer: My answer is very specific to the database. It has worked for this specific problem but I do not think it is the best approach. The answer I accepted is better.